# How to solve error while doing interpolation one point with many points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to interpolate many points to one point in MATLAB. But I am getting error

> *The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values.*

My code is given below

```
A = [2 6;3 7]
B = [3 6;4 9]
Xq=[A(:,1) [10;10]]
Yq=interp1(A,B,Xq','linear','extrap')
```

Actually I want to generate a line passing through one point from many points and as shown in below figure and extend upto axis of plot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'For loop' would be a solution.

One example is this.

```
A = [2 6;1 6;3 6]
B = [3 6;2 6;3 6]

L=size(A)
xArr=zeros(L(1), L(2));
yArr=zeros(L(1), L(2));

nLine=L(1); %number of lines

for k=1:nLine

    Xq=[A(k,:) 10]
    Yq=interp1(A(k,:),B(k,:),Xq','linear','extrap')

    xArr(:,k)=Xq';
    yArr(:,k)=Yq';
end
plot(xArr,yArr,'*-')
```

If you don't want to use for loop, you could directly calculate gradient and intercept of linear function.

```
A = [2 6;1 6;3 6]
B = [3 6;2 6;3 6]

L=size(A)

limX=10; %x limit

a=(B(:,2)-B(:,1))./(A(:,2)-A(:,1));  %gradient vector
b=B(:,1)-a.*A(:,1); % intercept vector
y=a*limX+b % linear function

Aq=[A';limX*ones(1,L(1))];
Bq=[B';y'];

figure(2)
plot(Aq,Bq,'*-')
```